# How can I reference an object with a dropdown input in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have models `Order` and `Vendor`. `Order` has `vendor`, `description`, `items`, `cost` fields, and `Vendor` has `name`, `email`, `phone`.

When a user creates a new `Order`, I would like them to select the Vendor's `name` from a dropdown input, which references the whole relevant `Vendor` objects in the `Order`'s `vendor` field.

Comment: So you want front end logic i.e how to show them in form right?

Comment: Yes, how would it show the Vendor's name in the dropdown, but reference the whole object when the name is selected.

Comment: collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)   use like this

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding. you have following associations

`Vendor has_many Orders`

`Order belongs_to Vendor [In order we need to store vendor_id]`

So in that case in your new order form you need to add
`<%= f.select(:Vendor_id, Vendor.all.collect { |v| [ v.name, v.id ] }, {}, { "data-placeholder": "Select Vendor" }) %>`

This will give you selected vender_id in parameters. Hope this will work for you.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Akshay, thanks for this. This 'select' code is what I am looking for, but can this be done without the associations? The Orders belong_to User in my app, and don't belong_to Vendor. Thanks for your help

Comment: yeah, you can use it without association as well. But If you need to fetch which order is belongs to which vendor. Then you need to add associations.

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer. If it works for you. Thanks!